# How do I validate an XML document against a DTD in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dtd

I don't want to do anything fancy, I just want to make sure a document is valid, and print an error message if it is not. Google pointed me to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379), but it seems XmlValidatingReader is obsolete (at least, that's what MonoDevelop tells me).

Edit: I'm trying Mehrdad's tip, but I'm having trouble. I think I've got most of it, but I can't find OnValidationEvent anywhere. Where go I get OnValidationEvent from?

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(/*trouble is here*/);
XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(fileToLoad, settings);
```

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "converting to C#". My code *is* in C# 3.0.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry, I wrote that while I was still learning C# 1.0, and didn't know that `var` was valid in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating [`XmlValidatingReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.aspx) directly, you should construct an appropriate [`XmlReaderSettings` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx) and pass it as an argument to the [`XmlReader.Create` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162474.aspx):

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD };
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(OnValidationEvent);
var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml", settings);
```

The rest is unchanged.

P.S. `OnValidationEvent` is the name of the method you declare to handle validation events. Obviously, you can remove the line if you don't want to subscribe to validation events raised by the `XmlReader`.

Comment: Matthew: That's the method you'd declare to handle failed validation events. You can remove that line altogether if you want it to throw exception instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var messages = new StringBuilder();
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD };
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => messages.AppendLine(args.Message);
var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml", settings);

if (messages.Length > 0)
{
    // Log Validation Errors
    // Throw Exception
    // Etc.
}
```

[ValidationEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationeventhandler.aspx)

[Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[Type Inference](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/03/17/lambda-inference)

Comment: Um, didn't Mehrdad give essentially the same answer, 22 minutes before you did?

Comment: This answer is a different way of accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've referred to this example on DTD validation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing?view=netcore-3.1#input

This example has invalid DTD XML, which I've corrected as below.

```
<!--XML file using a DTD-->
<!DOCTYPE store [
  <!ELEMENT store (item)*> 
  <!ELEMENT item (name,dept,price)>
  <!ATTLIST item type CDATA #REQUIRED ISBN CDATA 
#REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT dept (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>]>
<store>
  <item type="supplies"  ISBN="2-3631-4">
    <name>paint</name>
    <dept>1</dept>
    <price>16.95</price>
  </item>
</store>
```

Answer (score -1):

full description:

1. In Visual Studio .NET, create a new Visual C# Console Application
   project named `ValidateXml`. Add two using statements to the beginning
   of Class1.cs as follows:

   ```
   using System.Xml;        // for XmlTextReader and XmlValidatingReader
   using System.Xml.Schema; // for XmlSchemaCollection (which is used later)
   ```
2. In `Class1.cs`, declare a boolean variable named `isValid` before the
   start of the `Main` method as follows:

   ```
   private static bool isValid = true;      // If a validation error occurs,
                                            // set this flag to false in the
                                            // validation event handler.
   ```
3. Create an `XmlTextReader` object to read an XML document from a text
   file in the `Main` method, and then create an `XmlValidatingReader` to
   validate this XML data as follows:

   ```
   XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader("C:\\MyFolder\\ProductWithDTD.xml");
   XmlValidatingReader v = new XmlValidatingReader(r);
   ```
4. The `ValidationType` property of the `XmlValidatingReader` object
   indicates the type of validation that is required (DTD, XDR, or
   Schema). Set this property to DTD as follows:

   ```
   v.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
   ```
5. If any validation errors occur, the validating reader generates a
   validation event. Add the following code to register a validation
   event handler (you will implement the `MyValidationEventHandler`
   method in Step 7):

   ```
   v.ValidationEventHandler += 
      new ValidationEventHandler(MyValidationEventHandler);
   ```
6. Add the following code to read and validate the XML document. If any
   validation errors occur, `MyValidationEventHandler` is called to
   address the error. This method sets `isValid` to false (see Step 8).
   You can check the status of `isValid` after validation to see if the
   document is valid or invalid.

   ```
   while (v.Read())
   {
      // Can add code here to process the content.
   }
   v.Close();

   // Check whether the document is valid or invalid.
   if (isValid)
      Console.WriteLine("Document is valid");
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Document is invalid");
   ```
7. Write the `MyValidationEventHandler` method after the `Main` method as
   follows:

   ```
   public static void MyValidationEventHandler(object sender, 
                                               ValidationEventArgs args) 
   {
      isValid = false;
      Console.WriteLine("Validation event\n" + args.Message);
   }
   ```

Build and run the application. The application should report that the XML document is valid.
**e.g.:**
In Visual Studio .NET, modify `ProductWithDTD.xml` to invalidate it (for example, delete the `<AuthorName>M soliman</AuthorName>` element).
Run the application again. You should receive the following error message:

```
Validation event
Element 'Product' has invalid content. Expected 'ProductName'.
An error occurred at file:///C:/MyFolder/ProductWithDTD.xml(4, 5).
Document is invalid
```

Comment: Meh - this is just a copy/paste of some MSDN sample, nearly verbatim. At the very least, provide a reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379